# Node.js: Stripe error No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, stripe-payments

Error:

> "message": "No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing",

I've tried `req.rawBody`, but the same result. I ve also tried all the solutions available on stack overflow and github.

#### server.js

```
// use express body parser
app.use(bodyParse.json());
```

#### stripe.js

```
router
  .route('/payment/hook')
  .post(bodyParser.raw({
    type: 'application/json'
  }), paymentsController.transactionHook);
```

#### paymentsController.js

```
transactionHook: async(req, res, next) => {
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    let event;

    try {
      event = await stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, endpointSecret);

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message, detail: err.detail });
      }
  }
```

#### Response

[image: Response]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `bodyParser.json()` will modify the body such that the signatures are not verifiable. You need to ensure this middleware is **not** being applied for your webhook `/hook` endpoint.

One way to do this with Express is to simply define the webhook endpoint *before* you apply the middleware (in the sequence of building your routes).

Comment: I ve expose exposed the endpoint before the bodyParser.json() that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your support